# Monotonicity and convergence of the sequence $\{a_n\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $a_{n+1} = \frac{a_n}{2 + a_n}$ and $a_1 \gt 0 $ . Does the $\{a_n\}$ converge or diverge ? (If it's convergent find the value of limit .) Does the $\{a_n\}$ monotone ? (If it's monotone determine increasing sequence or decreasing . )

My teacher told me $a_{n+1} = f(a_n)$ is helpful in the problems like this but I can't use it .

Comment: @down voter Why?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see that $a_n > 0$ for all $n\geq 1$. Hence
$$0<a_{n+1} = \frac{a_n}{a_n+2} < \frac{a_n}{2}$$
which implies
$$0<a_{n+1} < \frac{1}{2^n}a_1$$
Now apply sandwich theorem.

Comment: How you got $0<a_{n+1} < \frac{1}{2^n}a_1$ ?

Comment: We have $$a_2 < \frac{a_1}{2}$$  $$a_3 < \frac{a_2}{2} < \frac{a_1}{2^2}$$ $$a_4 < \frac{a_3}{2} < \frac{a_2}{2^2} < \frac{a_1}{2^3}$$ You can do the same for all $a_n$.

Comment: And what about monotonicity ?

Comment: $a_{n+1} <\frac{a_n}{2} < a_n$ so the sequence decreases.

Comment: Thank you ! So that hint isn't useful ?

Comment: The hint is a systematic way of investigating the behavior of recurrence sequence. However, then facing a particular problem, it is better not to use the hint, although it might be useful sometimes.

Comment: Can you explain how I can use it generally ?